# LinqDataSource dynamic parameters - forcing an OR with WhereParameters

Tags: asp.net, linq, linqdatasource

In my "selecting" statement I need to add two dynamic parameters when using the [LinqDataSource's WhereParameters collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.whereparameters.aspx):

```
e.WhereParameters.Add(param, True)
```

However, the system adds these parameters as **`AND`**, but I want to perform an **`OR`** where either `parameter 1` OR `parameter 2` is true.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the number of params at design time, and can only determine at runtime, consider changing the `Where` property of the datasource at runtime. You can insert actual values yourself.

```
 //e.g. we know that we want 4 params this time.
 LinqDataSource1.Where = 
    "Alpha == 1 OR Brave==False OR Charlie> 'Jan 1 1999' or Delta = @DeltaVal";
 LinqDataSource1.WhereParameters.Add("DeltaVal", "O'Flanagan");
```

If you do know the *n* params at runtime, you could simply put the OR statement at design-time, and modify their values.

Perhaps put your `OR` clause right in the LinqDataSource declaration.

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server"          
     Where="Foo == @FooValue OR Bar==@BarValue">
```

Then you code-behind can add those two `where` parameters.

```
LinqDataSource1.WhereParameters.Add("FooValue", "milk");
LinqDataSource1.WhereParameters.Add("BarValue", "eggs");
```

Comment: The problem in using this method is that I don't know which of about 8 different "foovalue" or "barvalue" I will be using in the common control.  Hence adding the whereparameter dynamically rather than pre-declaring it.

I may see if I can add two generic values and then change the name of the property at runtime...

Comment: @Carl: update to show how to modify the where and parameters at runtime.

Comment: @Carl: did this update help you? If you need any more help, please comment. Please remember to upvote and 'accept answers' as part of the StackOverflow community!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Joe Albahari's [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).  I've used it with great success.